# Transforming SQL many to many JOIN with a constraint into DAX/PowerBI

Tags: sql, join, powerbi, dax

I'm trying recreate a join between 2 tables, timeregistration and schedule, into one table which I then filter based the difference between the scheduled start time and the actual start time. Basically; I'm trying to determine whether a employee is late or early.

My query in SQL looks like this and works as desired, I just can't seem to figure out how to make this join work in DAX for Power BI, let alone the time constraint.

```
SELECT 
    tr.employee_employeeID AS EmployeeID, 
    tr.rawstarttime AS Actual_Start, 
    s.StartTime_Schedule AS Schedule_Start

FROM 
    timeregistration tr, 
    schedule s
WHERE 
    tr.Employee_EmployeeID = s.Employee_EmployeeID
AND 
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, tr.RawStartTime, s.StartDateTime) < 60
AND 
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, tr.RawEndTime, s.StartDateTime) > -60
```

And the tables and relation look something like this: 
[Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEhqQ.png)
I have tried the following so far:

`GENERATE(timeregistration; schedule)`
 - which returned
 
`The Column with the name of 'EmployeeID' already exists in the 'date_diff' Table.`

`NATURALINNERJOIN(timeregistration; schedule)`
  - which returned
`No common join columns detected. The join function 'NATURALINNERJOIN' requires at-least one common join column.`

`CROSSJOIN(timeregistration; schedule)` 
 - which returned
 `The Column with the name of 'EmployeeID' already exists in the 'date_diff' Table.`

As of right now I wouldn't really know what to do with the JOIN, so any help would be appreciated.

With kind regards,
Martien

(edit: Fixed formatting mistakes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with this DAX query

```
date_diff = 
 FILTER(
    ADDCOLUMNS( 
        GENERATEALL(
            schedule;
            VAR schedule_id = schedule[EmployeeID]
            RETURN 
                SELECTCOLUMNS(
                CALCULATETABLE( 
                    timeregistration;
                    timeregistration[EmployeeID] = schedule_id
                );
                "StartTime_timeregistration"; timeregistration[StartTime_actual]
                )
        );
        "diff"; DATEDIFF([StartTime_schedule];[StartTime_timeregistration];SECOND)
    );
    3600 >= [diff] &&
    -3600 <= [diff] &&
    NOT(ISBLANK([StartTime_timeregistration]))
)
```